# How to add listeners in calendar component in Ext JS?

Tags: extjs, calendar, event-listener

How to add listeners to catch some changes in events in calendar component Ext.calendar.panel.Panel? Following [this post](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?353026-Sencha-Calendar-Events-are-not-syncing-with-server), I tried all listed events, but none of them is working.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3bjh)

Comment: May you create some fiddle sample with calendar and explain a little bit more about "some changes in events".

Comment: I added fiddle. So, I would like to trap when calendar event is created by mouseup, and also when event is moved (dragged and dropped), and when event is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen on Ext.calendar.store.Events.html [events](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/classic/Ext.calendar.store.Events.html#events). Something like:

```
Ext.define('CalApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.calendar.panel.Panel',

    createButton: {
        hidden: true
    },

    defaultView: 'week',

    store: {
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'calendars.json'
        },
        eventStoreDefaults: {
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'events.json'
            },
            listeners: {
                // Listen add event
                add: function(store, addedEventRecords) {
                    Ext.Array.each(addedEventRecords, function(eventRecord) {
                        console.log(eventRecord.getData());
                    });
                }
            }
        },
    },

    listeners: {

    }

});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    mainView: 'CalApp.view.main.Main'
});
```

Or listening the events of the views:

```
Ext.define('CalApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.calendar.panel.Panel',

    createButton: {
        hidden: true
    },

    defaultView: 'week',

    store: {
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'calendars.json'
        },
        eventStoreDefaults: {
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'events.json'
            }
        },
        
    },

    views: {
        day: {
            xtype: 'calendar-day',
            titleTpl: '{start:date("l F d, Y")}',
            controlStoreRange: false,
            label: 'Day',
            weight: 10,
            dayHeader: null
        },
        week: {
            xtype: 'calendar-week',
            dayHeaderFormat: 'D d',
            controlStoreRange: false,
            titleTpl: '{start:date("j M")} - {end:date("j M Y")}',
            label: 'Week',
            weight: 20,
            listeners: {
                beforeeventadd: function (view, context, eOpts) {
                    console.log(context.event.data); //Some Event Data
                    return false;
                },
                beforeeventedit: function (view, context, eOpts) {
                    console.log(context.event.data); //Some Event Data
                    return false;
                },
                beforeeventtap: function (view, context, eOpts) {
                    console.log(context.event.data); //Some Event Data
                    return false;
                },
                validateeventedit: function (view, context, eOpts) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(context.event.data); //Some Event Data
                    return false;
                },

            }

        },
        month: {
            xtype: 'calendar-month',
            titleTpl: '{start:date("F Y")}',
            label: 'Month',
            weight: 30
        }
    },

});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    mainView: 'CalApp.view.main.Main'
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I somehow cancel update event? I tried to put return false in update event, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @FlashGordon please have a look at the updated post, you can also listen some view events..